# Why there is a !mark in the output but I never type any in my code?

Tags: c, output, cs50

The following is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    char out;
    string key = NULL;
    if(argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for( int i = 0, s = strlen(argv[1]) ; i < s; i++)
    {
        if( s!=26)
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(isdigit(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if(!isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
           printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
           return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            key = argv[1];
        }
    }
    string yy = get_string("Enter: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for( int x = 0; x < 26; x++ )
    {

        if(isalpha(yy[x]))
        {
            if(islower(yy[x]))
            {
                printf("%c",tolower(key[yy[x]-97]));
            }
            else if(isupper(yy[x]))
            {
                printf("%c",toupper(key[yy[x]-65]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c",yy[x]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The following is the output:

```
$ ./substitution JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ
Enter: Hello
ciphertext: Vkxxn!
```

When I want to check my work:

```
:) substitution.c exists
:) substitution.c compiles
:( encrypts "A" as "Z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
    expected "ciphertext: Z\...", not "ciphertext: Z\..."
:( encrypts "a" as "z" using ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA as key
    expected "ciphertext: z\...", not "ciphertext: z\..."
:( encrypts "ABC" as "NJQ" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
    expected "ciphertext: NJ...", not "ciphertext: NJ..."
:( encrypts "XyZ" as "KeD" using NJQSUYBRXMOPFTHZVAWCGILKED as key
    expected "ciphertext: Ke...", not "ciphertext: Ke..."
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZTEOGXHCIPJSQD as key
    expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not "ciphertext: Cb..."
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd as key
    expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not "ciphertext: Cb..."
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd as key
    expected "ciphertext: Cb...", not "ciphertext: Cb..."
:( encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
    expected "ciphertext: Rq...", not "ciphertext: Rq..."
:) handles lack of key
:) handles too many arguments
:) handles invalid key length
:) handles invalid characters in key
:( handles duplicate characters in key
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( handles multiple duplicate characters in key
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
```

Why I get the "!" in the result and How do I fix it?

Comment: Your loop goes up to index 25, but your input string only has 5 characters. You're getting undefined behavior because you're accessing outside the string.

Comment: off topic : May i suggest ```key[yy[x] - 'a' ] ``` . It might make your code a bit more readable

Comment: Use `x < strlen(yy)` instead of `x < 26`.

Comment: Off topic: The condition that prints `printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");` doesn't actually check the number of characters. It just checks whether they gave the key argument.

Comment: Oh thx, a stupid mistake

Comment: Look at an ASCII chart and see where the ! character is.  Combined with the above comments and a debugger, it will be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Your input "Hello" appears to have 5 characters, and your output has at least 6 characters.  This means your output loop `for( int x = 0; x < 26; x++ )` has the wrong boundary conditions.  A suitable fix would use the length of the string `yy` instead of the hard-coded value of 26.  As you assume the input encoding is ASCII "C", you can also eliminate the call to isalpha(c) as "it is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c))".:

```
    for( int x = 0; x < strlen(yy); x++ ) {
        if(islower(yy[x])) {
            printf("%c",tolower(key[yy[x]-97]));
        } else if(isupper(yy[x])) {
            printf("%c",toupper(key[yy[x]-65]));
        } else {
            printf("%c",yy[x]);
        }
    }
```

Each of 3 branches of the if-statement does `printf("%c ", ...)` so you could refactor the code so it does the print unconditionally, and move the logic to transform the value into a separate function `encrypt()`:

```
int encrypt(char *key, int c) {
    return islower(c) ?
        tolower(key[c - 'a']) :
        (isupper(c) ? key[c - 'A'] : c);
}

...

    for(int x = 0; x < strlen(yy); x++) {
        printf("%c", encrypt(key, yy[x]));
    }
```